# isset for link - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm attempting to create a link for users to click that will remove them from a list. I'm trying to figure out how to do this without using a submit button and without using $_GET(if possible).

Anyway, I'm afraid to do it with $_GET (the way I have it now), because the user can type this in the URL (even though 99% wouldn't know how or think to do this) and they would be removed from the list.

How can I name the link so I can use $_POST?

```
$attendingUsers = mysql_query("Select acceptedInvites from events where eventID = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['eventID'])." ");
    $users= mysql_fetch_array($attendingUsers);
    $user = $users['acceptedInvites'];
 if(preg_match("/$userid/", $user)){
        echo "You are attending this event</br>";
        echo '<a href="viewevent.php?eventID='.$_GET['eventID'].'&delete=1">Click here </a>to remove yourself from the list';
            if($_GET['delete']=1){
                    $sql=...
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to do this without using $_GET? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Never delete via a link. Read [The Spider of Doom](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx)

Best way is to link to a "delete" page with an "are you sure" form. Submitting the form (via POST) performs the delete and redirects back to a suitable results page.

For example

```
<a href="remove.php?eventID=<?php echo $eventId ?>">Click here</a>
to remove yourself from the list
```

Then, in `remove.php`

```
<?php
// get Event details via $_GET['eventID']

if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
    // delete via SQL

    // redirect
    header('Location: http://example.com/events.php');
    exit;
}

// display event details
?>

<form method="post" action="remove.php?eventID=<?php echo $eventId ?>">
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Remove me from this event">
</form>
```

You should probably also look into CSRF protection but that's really outside the scope of this question.

Comment: How can I use $_POST for a link? I'm not sure how to name it.I know how to check if something has been posted, I'm just not sure on the naming of it.

Comment: Thanks for the update, it makes more sense but I'm still confused on one aspect. When the user clicks the link and it goes to remove.php, how can I still display the contents ofthe event (from event.php) when the user is now on remove.php?

Answer (score 1):

Your are required to use either `$_GET` or `$_POST`

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="yourEventId" />
   <a href="#" onclick="this.form.submit();" > Delete</a>
</form>
```

Comment: how can I use $_POST for the link? I guess what I'm trying to ask is how to name the link so I can use $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

If I have my JavaScript right, this should do the trick:

```
<a href="javascript:void(document.getElementById('delete').submit());">Delete</a>
<form id="delete" action="delete.php" method="post">
    ...
</form>
```

The link will then submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of encoding to make the get var unreadable, like an md5 or even an encrypted string.